# Was testing for midichlorians done covertly?

Tags: star-wars, midichlorians

Various commentators have suggested that one of the reasons knowledge of the Jedi dies out so fast in Rogue One is that there were so few Jedi compared to the wider galactic population (I believe I've seen one post here that talks about a trillion people on Coruscant and around 100,000 Jedi in the galaxy). However it's also known in-universe that every child is tested for their midichlorian count. If true, then this suggests it was done covertly, otherwise the conversation would go something like:

"We're going to just check his Midichlorian count now, Mr Fett"
"His what? You're doing what now? Hands off my Boba!"

[screaming]

So is there any indication whether testing was done overtly or covertly?

Comment: One can draw a sample overtly, without indicating everything one is testing for. People now, on our planet, get blood samples drawn all of the time for all kinds of things.

Comment: My answer to the dupe indicates that midi-chlorian blood-testing in children was **mandatory**. So no, it wasn't done covertly, at least within the Republic.

Comment: This may also give you some idea of how it "goes down" with the parents; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114185/how-does-taking-a-force-sensitive-youngling-to-the-jedi-temple-go-down

Comment: Looking at that, it's not really a duplicate - the link talks about what happens once the child is known to have a high midichlorian count (which response in itself would make people more, not less, aware of the Jedi). Even if the testing was done without telling the parents, who is doing it? 100k Jedi themselves wouldn't have the manpower; I can't see a solution that wouldn't involve large numbers of people.

Comment: The proposed existing answer at the top of the page doesn't address the point of this question, which is how the testing was done in a way that didn't make the galactic population aware of the Jedi.

Comment: The question as written just asks whether the testing was done overtly or covertly, the answer to the dupe covers that.  If what you really want to know is how come that testing didn't mean that everybody knew the Jedi were real, you should probably rephrase.

Comment: ... but I don't see the problem.  The fact that the old government carried out blood tests for potential Jedi doesn't prove anything, and would be particularly unconvincing if (as would usually be the case) you never heard first-hand of anybody testing positive.